# Sound and Mose movement stutters in Windows 7

Tags: windows, audio, windows-7-x64

I am facing this issue for now around more than 1 month and not able to find a fix for this.

Problem-1: My 5 year old, Dell XPS, L502X, having Windows 7. When I play any movie\youtube video\songs I notice sound stutter continuously. Movies\Videos becomes slow as well. Its really frustrating.

Problem-2: I use the in-built mouse Synaptics Pointing Device, which every now then stop and moves, again stuttering.

I have read my blogs\forums on this. They suggest the following which I have tried but none worked:-
1) Update the drivers (all the drivers are up-to-date)
2) reinstalling the drivers (did not work either)
3) to download tools and see which process is the issue. (found svchost local network was culprit, but that is a mandate process\services which starts again and the issues start again.)
4) Windows Update - (installed the updates but still the same issue)
5) Restored my Windows to the point i received it (eveything is removed and factory reset but the issues seems to persist).
6) Ran Anitvirus\Malware (it did not find anything)
7) If I run my laptop after hibernating, then the issue does not occur for a long period of time.

Please please help me out with suggestions what might be the issue ?

Does this happen due to age of the components ?
Will installing Win 8/10 help ?

Laptop Configuration 
 1. Dell xps L502X
 2. 8 GB Ram
 3. intel code i7
 4. NVidia GeForce GT 540M
 5. Windows 7 Home Premium with SP-1 (64-bit OS)
6. Realtek HD Audio

Comment: I have the same problem, without solution yet. I though it was the motherboard, but I changed it and the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

After more research I found help regarding the "latency" and use the tool to identify the problem, [DP Latency Checker](http://www.thesycon.de/eng/latency_check.shtml) I started **disabling** some of my components from Device Manager.

I disabled the following and it reduced (sometimes its completely eradicated) the Audio Stuttering. But then again it comes and goes, and sometimes stays for a long time. Since the stuttering is still occurring I am not completely sure and whether they helped me to at least reduce it somewhat.

1. NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M
2. Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

One thing I notice is whenever charging my laptop the stuttering returns. After its completely charged it goes away and happens rarely for a very short time (which can be ignored).

**Experiment 2 :** Since I notice while charging the laptop and watching\listening Video\Audio this is happening. **I will be fully charging my laptop first, remove the charger and watch the performance on battery.**

Answer (score 0):

Another useful tool for this issue is [Latency Monitor](https://www.resplendence.com/latencymon). As its site explains:

> LatencyMon checks if a system running Windows is suitable for
>   processing real-time audio and other tasks. LatencyMon analyzes the
>   possible causes of buffer underruns by measuring kernel timer
>   latencies and reporting [DPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call) and [ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) excecution times as well as hard
>   [pagefaults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). It will provide a comprehensible report and find the
>   kernel modules and processes responsible for causing audio latencies
>   which result in drop outs. It also provides the functionality of an
>   ISR monitor, DPC monitor and a hard pagefault monitor.
>
> LatencyMon will display the highest latencies of a kernel timer and
>   report the highest execution times of ISR and DPC routines as well as
>   hard pagefaults. In most cases it will also find the drivers and
>   processes responsible for executing them. It will create a
>   comprehensible report which also displays all sampled data in a
>   detailed manner allowing you to perform in-depth analysis.

This is not a solution, but could put other people with audio dropouts, clicks or pops, in track of the problem.

Resuming some ideas I read about it, sometimes its related to power managment ([ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)), the some people recommends to to make sure your Windows Power Scheme is set to *'Always On'* under Windows XP, or *'High Performance'* with Windows Vista and Windows 7. If at all possible, you should also permanently disable any hardware throttling scheme in your computer's BIOS, the most common being [EIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) (Enhanced Intel Speedstep Technology) and C1E enhanced halt state.

Another source of problem could be a driver running in your system executing for too long. If any kernel-mode device driver in your Windows system is implemented improperly it can causes excessive latencies of Deferred Procedure Calls. So disabling the network adapter could for example, "solve" the problem. Another possible solution is updating drivers or using generic ones.

However this is very dependent on the current situation of the system. When its connected to a (large) network, there may be very many small DPCs raised for the network packets that are received by your computer. When you unplug your computer (or everyone goes home) this DPC storm suddenly stops.

Hope it helps at least a bit in understanding the problem.